# Effect of small change in probability distribution on error probability

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, it.information-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable and $Y=f(X)$ where $f$ is a deterministic function. Moreover, assume that there exists a deterministic function $g(.)$ such that the following probability is small.
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}[g(Y)\neq X]\leq\delta.
\end{align}
Assume that $X'$ is another random variable which is close to $X$ in terms of total variation distance, i.e., $\|p_X-p_{X'}\|_1\leq\epsilon$. What can be said about the following possibility?
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}[g(f(X'))\neq X']\leq?.
\end{align}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand\de\delta\newcommand\ep\epsilon$Let $h:=g\circ f$, so that $g(Y)=h(X)$ and $g(f(X'))=h(X')$. Let $A:=\{x\colon h(x)\ne x)$. Then the condition $P(g(Y)\ne X)\le\de$ can be written as
$$\int_A p_X\le\de.$$

So,
$$P(g(f(X'))\ne X')=P(h(X')\ne X')=\int_A p_{X'} \\
=\int_A p_X+\int_A (p_{X'}-p_X)
\le\int_A p_X+\|p_X-p_{X'}\|_1\le\de+\ep.$$

Here we used the inequalities $\int_A (p_{X'}-p_X)\le\int_A |p_{X'}-p_X|\le\|p_X-p_{X'}\|_1$.

---

Working slightly harder and letting $u_+:=\max(0,u)$, we can write
$$\int_A (p_{X'}-p_X)\le\int_A (p_{X'}-p_X)_+
\le\int (p_{X'}-p_X)_+=\frac12\,\int|p_X-p_{X'}| \\ 
=\frac12\,\|p_X-p_{X'}\|_1.$$
(The penultimate inequality above follows because $|p_X-p_{X'}|=(p_{X'}-p_X)_+ + (p_X-p_{X'})_+$, $p_X-p_{X'}=(p_X-p_{X'})_+ - (p_{X'}-p_X)_+$, and $\int(p_X-p_{X'})=0$, so that $\int(p_X-p_{X'})_+=\int(p_{X'}-p_X)_+=\frac12\,\int|p_X-p_{X'}|$.)
So, we get
$$P(g(f(X'))\ne X')\le\de+\ep/2.$$

Answer (score 3):

While your question already has an answer, I'm including the following purely as you have tagged this question "information theory", and from an information-theoretic perspective the answer to your question is "this immediately follows from DPI (data processing inequality)". Details follow.

For distributions on $\Omega$, define $F: \Omega\to\{0,1\}$ by
$$F(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & (g\circ f)(x) \neq x\\
0 & \text{else}
\end{cases}.$$

Write $\Delta(X, Y) = \frac{1}{2}\lVert X - Y\rVert_1$ for the total variation distance.
Then by the Data-Processing Inequality

$$\Delta(F(X), F(X')) \leq \Delta(X, X') = \frac{\lVert X-X'\rVert_1}{2}.$$

Note that each of $F(X), F(X')$ are Bernoulli random of parameter $p, p'$, where $p, p'$ are the probabilities you want to bound.
It is straightforward to compute that

$$\Delta(F(X), F(X')) = \left|p-p'\right|.$$

It then follows that $|p-p'| \leq \frac{\lVert X-X'\rVert_1}{2}$, and therefore

\begin{align*}
\max(p,p') - \min(p,p') &= |p-p'| \\
&\leq \frac{\lVert X-X'\rVert_1}{2}\\
\implies p' \leq \max(p,p') 
&\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}+\delta.
\end{align*}

Note that this immediately implies that you get something similar whenever you have a bound on $D_f(X||X')$, where $D_f(\cdot||\cdot)$ is an [$f$-divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-divergence), though instead of the expression $\Delta(F(X), F(X')) = |p-p'|$ you will get the expression $p'f\left(\frac{p}{p'}\right)+(1-p') f\left(\frac{1-p}{1-p'}\right)$.
This reduces to the claimed expression when $f(x) = |x-1|$ (as for this $f$ $\Delta(X,Y) = D_f(X||Y)$).